# sql Query to find specific value from all columns

Tags: mysql

```
      S1 S2 S3 S4 S5  
1.    1 1  
2.    1    1     1 
3.    1
4.    1   1   1    1
```

I want to create a query where I put S1 = 1 and get the below output

```
   S1  S2  S3 S4 S5 
3.  1
```

Is there a way to put any kind of where only statement like where only S1 = 1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: Fix your design.

Comment: E.g.: http://rextester.com/DQMN65593